# socket.io doesn't work in webkit mobile with node.js

Tags: node.js, mobile, webkit, socket.io

i'm using this node.js code:

```
var server = require("socket.io").listen(6666);

server.sockets.on("connection", function(message)
{
        message.on("newMessage", function(data)
        {
                server.sockets.emit("sendEvent", data);
        });
});
```

and this html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Online chat</title>
<style>
body
{
    color: #333;
    background: #333;
    font-family: "Helvetica", Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.container
{
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 90%;
}

input
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 95%;
}

span
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 95%;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
<script src="/resources/js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var websocket = io.connect("http://localhost:6666");

window.onload = function()
{
    websocket.on("sendEvent", function(data)
    {
        var chat = document.getElementById('zchat');
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        var txt = document.createTextNode(data);
        span.appendChild(txt);              
        if(chat.hasChildNodes())
            chat.insertBefore(span, chat.firstChild);
        else
            chat.appendChild(span);
    });

    var form = document.getElementById('zform');
    var message = document.getElementById('zmessage');  
    form.onsubmit = function(e)
    {
        websocket.emit("newMessage", message.value);     
        return false;
    };
};
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form id="zform">
            <label>Message: </label>
            <input type="text" name="zmessage" id="zmessage" placeholder="Please insert message" required />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>     
    </div>
    <div id="zchat" class="container">
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

works fine with normal browsers but with i probe with samsung's bada's "dolfin" browser based on webkit and it doesn't work, can someone probe it with another mobile browser? thanks :)

Comment: > Oh, and Dolfin ought not to be confused with Dolphin, which is a skin for Android WebKit. < Not sure if Samsung Dolfin uses webkit. :/

Comment: i think is for node.js version i'm going to use latest version :)

Comment: Node.js is server side, it shouldn't affect a specific browser.

Comment: in chromium / chrome neither... and i'm using the latest version v0.6.6. 
with: http://clab.nodester.com:80 server t works fine...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

server.js

```
//...
var server = require("socket.io").listen(6969);
//...
```

index.html

```
//...
var websocket = io.connect("http://192.168.100.103:6969");
//...
```

i think the SATAN's port is evil for this, jajajaja and NEVER use localhost, always the PC's public IP

Comment: Why does it have to be 6969? Whats wrong with 80 or any other?

Comment: to don't start a server with root privileges